# How to have a Gradient Layer's size placed behind a UITextField, match the UITextField size, after re-sizing the layout?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, cagradientlayer

What you will see in the first image, if you scroll down a little bit, is the initial screen of a fin app. Basically, every section you see on the screen is placed within a vertical Stack View. Then every Label and Cell Is placed in a horizontal Stack View and so on, so the app auto-resizes for any screen size. I was using Story Board to create the elements.

The last section has two blue UITextFields that have a gradient layer behind it. I created an extension UITextField Class in a separate file that has the gradient function constructor in it and then another Class that placed the gradient behind any UITextField that have that class attached like this:

```
extension UITextField {
    func gradientBackground(firstColor: UIColor, secondColor: UIColor){
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = [firstColor.cgColor, secondColor.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x:0.0, y:0.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)
        layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    }
}

class gradientToTextField: UITextField {
    var once = true
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        if once {
            self.gradientBackground(firstColor: UIColor(red: 0.30, green: 0.55, blue: 1.00, alpha: 1), secondColor: UIColor(red: 0.00, green: 0.36, blue: 1.00, alpha: 1))
            once = false
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
Now if you take a look at the second image on the right, the last section expands on tapping the Plus sign button. As a result, the third section(starting with Total) is hidden and a new stack view appears below within the same section. Everything resizes perfectly except the gradient layer. I have set a red background behind it which is the UITextField's Background, so the problem is highlighted. It appears that the Gradient Layer is shorter in height than the UITextField, which is its parent element.

Here's the full project on GitHub: https://github.com/silviuisidor/layerResizeProblem

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl:dr** — Instead of gradient layer that is a sublayer of the text field, you use a gradient view with the text field as its subview.

#### More details

Instead of a gradient layer, use a gradient *view*. The view exists purely to host a gradient layer as its underlying layer; you arrange this by subclassing UIView and implementing `layerClass` to return `CAGradientLayer.self`.

```
class MyGradientView : UIView {
    override class var layerClass : AnyClass { return CAGradientLayer.self }
    private func config() {
        let gradientLayer = self.layer as! CAGradientLayer
        let firstColor = UIColor(red: 0.30, green: 0.55, blue: 1.00, alpha: 1)
        let secondColor = UIColor(red: 0.00, green: 0.36, blue: 1.00, alpha: 1)
        gradientLayer.colors = [firstColor.cgColor, secondColor.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x:0.0, y:0.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame:frame)
        self.config()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder:coder)
        self.config()
    }
}
```

Now make the text field the *subview* of our gradient view. Pin it using autolayout to the center of the gradient view. The gradient view, with its text field subview, is what goes into the interface. When the animation takes place, it is the gradient view that is resized! And when that happens, the text field is automatically repositioned along with it.

[image]

Comment: I am trying to adjust my code to your advice. Be back in a minute

Comment: Added a "screencast" animated gif to show that this works as desired.

Comment: @vacawama You're absolutely right - at the very least he needs to know how to make the gradient view...

Comment: Your solution works really well. Thanks! I still have to choose the best answer tho. So I am trying to better understand your code. What does required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder:coder)
        self.config()
    } do?

Comment: You might want to set this all up in the storyboard. If you do, that's the initializer that will be called. — The key thing about my approach, as the screencast shows, is that it works with animation. Overriding `layoutSubviews` doesn't; the layer will jump instead of animating. I thought that was the problem you were trying to solve?

Comment: Thank you for finally asking the question properly! You finally asked the _real_ question, so that I was able to give you the answer I've been hinting at in your previous questions.

Comment: Thank you! Ya really offered me the "framework" so I learnt how to ask THE Questions.

Answer (score 1):

Resizing the layer frame in `layoutSubviews` should solve your problem

```
extension UITextField {
    func gradientBackground(firstColor: UIColor, secondColor: UIColor) -> CAGradientLayer{
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        gradientLayer.colors = [firstColor.cgColor, secondColor.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x:0.0, y:0.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)
        layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
        return gradientLayer
    }
}

class gradientToTextField: UITextField {
    var coloredLayer : CAGradientLayer! = nil

    var once = true
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        if once {
            coloredLayer = self.gradientBackground(firstColor: UIColor(red: 0.30, green: 0.55, blue: 1.00, alpha: 1), secondColor: UIColor(red: 0.00, green: 0.36, blue: 1.00, alpha: 1))
            once = false
        }
        coloredLayer.frame = self.bounds
    }
}
```

Comment: No. That will cause the gradient layer size to _jump_. He wants it to _animate_ along with the text field.

Comment: I'm getting this error message while implementing the code: "Cannot assign value of type '()' to type 'CAGradientLayer?' " Why?

Comment: @ISS, notice that `gradientBackground()` now returns the `CAGradientLayer`.

Comment: @vacawama Yeah, but how to I fix it?

Comment: @ISS, look at the code carefully.  `gradientBackground` now has a return type `-> CAGradientLayer` and a new line of code `return gradientLayer`.  If you implement those, your error should go away.

Comment: @vacawama Oh ya got it. Thanks!

Comment: @vacawama : Thanks a lot sir for handling quires of OP by commenting :) I wasn't online so did not notice :) Really kind :D Thanks once again :)

Comment: @SandeepBhandari, no problem.  I had written the nearly identical answer but you posted first, so I was very familiar with the code. ;-)

Comment: @SandeepBhandari Thanks man for this solution. It works really good in the end. I'll have to try the other answer solution and then give the vote for the best answer. Really made my day man!

Comment: @vacawama : Saw that :) You are very considerate and kind to help out OP even when u have deleted your answer :) Hence respect and grateful :)

Comment: @iss : No issues mate, take your time, try all possible options and stick with one that works the best for your requirement :)