# Animate a UIView who contains a CAGradientLayer

Tags: swift, animation, gradient

I want to modify the width of a view who have a gradientLayer but when I add the gradient layer this block the animation.

I show you my code :

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    animateProgressBar(leftPourcentage : 64)
    addGradientBarColor()
}

func addGradientBarColor(leftPourcentage : CGFloat){
    let leftColor = UIColor(rgb: 0x00ABBD)
    let rightColor = UIColor(rgb : 0x00DAFF)
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = [leftColor.cgColor,
                            rightColor.cgColor]

    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.frame = CGRect.init(
        x: userBarLeft.bounds.origin.x,
        y: userBarLeft.bounds.origin.y,
        width: userBarLeft.frame.width,
        height: userBarLeft.frame.height)
    gradientLayer.masksToBounds = false
    gradientLayer.cornerRadius = 2
    userBarLeft.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
}

func animateProgressBar(leftPourcentage : CGFloat){
    let widthOfTotalBarLeft = totalBarLeft.bounds.size.width

    leftBarWidthConstr.constant = widthOfTotalBarLeft * (leftPourcentage / 100)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    } 
}
```

This show me :

[image]

no animation work.

When I delete the `addGradientBarColor` function this show me :

[image]

I want the animation but with the gradient. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You cannot animate the layout of a layer using view animation (`UIView.animate`). Use a gradient _view_ instead of a gradient layer. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51543409/how-to-have-a-gradient-layers-size-placed-behind-a-uitextfield-match-the-uitex/51543591#51543591

Answer (score 0):

This is because you set the gradient width to be

```
width: userBarLeft.frame.width,
```

so make it

```
width:0,
```

and animate it's width

Comment: thanks to your reply, when I add this `self.gradientLeftLayer.bounds.size.width = widthOfTotalBarLeft * (leftPourcentage / 100)` in the `animate` section this don't work. How can I animate the width of a `CAGradientLayer` ?

Comment: Embed the gradient inside a view and animate it's complete frame